# split и пустые строки

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, split

Такое дело. Когда делаю так,

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = reader.readLine();
String[] m = s.split(".+\\?|(=)\\w+|.\\d+|&+");
        for (String e : m) {
                System.out.println(e + " ");
                    }
```

передаю такое например

```
alpha/index.html?lvl=15&view&name=Amigo
```

на выходе получаю это:

```
(пробел)lvl(пробел)(пробел)view(пробел)name
```

откуда берутся эти пробелы или строки пустые, как их убрать с помощью регулярки?

Comment: Не зря есть поговорка, что если вы решили проблему решить регуляркой, у вас появляется еще одна проблема :) Почему нельзя было использовать какой-нибудь библиотекой для парсинга? Кст, а вы получаете именно часть url или весь url, включая протокол?

Comment: В задании сказано получить параметры только.

Comment: У вас в массиве пустые строки, они всегда появляются в начале (когда совпадение найдено в начале строки) и между 2 по порядку совпадений. Воспользуйтесь парсером URL.

Comment: то есть, если решать это через split, то пустые строки всегда будут появляться так?

Comment: Нет, но могут...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для разбивки строки можно использовать код

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String s = reader.readLine();
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\?|\\&)(\\w+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
//здесь можно заполнить массив
System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: а что означает вот это в регулярке "?<=\\?" ?

Comment: (?<=[template]) условие впереди, которое в результат не попадает

Comment: Спасибо. Понял.